# How to get a sidebar with header fixed top, container scrollable and footer fixed bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I'm trying to make a sidebar and this is what I'm expecting:
[image]

- **Header fixed top** and **Footer fixed bottom** ( I don't know if 'fixed' is the right term, but I want them not to overlap the sidebar container )
- **Scrollable sidebar-container**

I tried to play with position of the **div** but it didn't work.
I also tried sticky footer's approach and It didn't work so well. 
I tried googling my problem, but most answers are the whole layout of the website.
I need it working inside my sidebar.

Here's my: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geddemet/XCn7C/5/)

The code is kinda long so I'm just gonna post the **CSS**:

```
        html, body {
            height: 100%;           
        }


        #wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;            
            margin: 0 auto -60px;
        }

        #push, #footer {
            height: 60px;
        }

        .container-fluid {    
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 60px;
            top: 42px;
            right: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #sidebar {    
            position:absolute;
            width:300px;
            height:100%;                    
        }

        #sidebar .ul-menu {
            margin:0px;
        }

        #sidenavbar .tabs-left>.nav-tabs>li>a{    
            margin: 0px;
            min-width: 30px;
            width: 70px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
            border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
            border: 0px;
        }

        .sidebar-tab-content {
            background: #FFF;
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            left: 94px;
            width:100%;
        }

        #sidenavbar .tabs-left>.nav-tabs {
            border: 0px;
        }      

        #footer {
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #666;
        }

    .side-header, .side-footer {
        background: #AAF;    
    }
    h2 {
        margin: 0px;
   }
```

Comment: Let me frankly tell you man. Thats an ugly looking layout

Comment: You desired output is exactly what you pasted from the fiddle. So im a bit confused here

Comment: Yeah I know, It's just a sample code. More important to me is to solve my question.

Comment: What is your question exactly. Read my 2nd comment

Comment: No it doesn't, look at the container between the header and footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the ideas. I solve my problem just now by adding these **css codes**:

```
       .side-header {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        .side-container {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40px;
            top: 40px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .side-footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/geddemet/XCn7C/

This community is really helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I use this for my [footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html). it works for me, the header and footer stay in the same place and the footer will expand if the content with the scroll bar  gets bigger. As for the box with the scroll bar, I believe you need to have something like `overflow:hidden` in the CSS for the box that you want to have a scroll bar on.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `overflow: auto` to your content div.

See this [minimal example](http://jsfiddle.net/XCn7C/14/) of how it would work.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my sample

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/33qu4/1/)

It was not good when you set place the side bar and right content into position absolute. Your design should have to get you in trouble if right content is not predictable and make more custom on it.

```
.sidebar-tab-content {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px; /*you could change it to 100% depend your need*/
}
```

Edited: Please look inside my jsfiddle sample code instead, the above proportion of CSS which I placed here was just small one of the changes

Comment: His content has no height specified.

Comment: @msbodetti as I saw, he has set it to 100%, and I also noticed that he could remove it already. What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that, only saw it now!

Answer (score -2):

Your looking for `position: fixed`

[FIDDLE Full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/XCn7C/10/embedded/result/) [Normal Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCn7C/10/)

CSS:

```
 .side-header{
            background: #AAF;  
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
        }
 .side-footer {
            background: #AAF;
            position:fixed;
            bottom:60px;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

But you are going to have to play around with the width's because it's taking the container width div.